# Don't understand Insert function too well, getting an error I can't seem to get past

Tags: c++, insert

I am trying to insert an user inputted name into a pre-existing string, and i keep getting an error stating that:

> "[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string::insert(std::basic_string::iterator, std::string&)'"
>   on line 25

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string custName = " ";
string firstName = " ";
string midInitial = " ";
string lastName = " ";
string getFullName = "";
string comma = ",";

int getName()
{
    cout<<"Please enter your first name \n";
    cin>>firstName;
    cout<<"Please enter your middle initial \n";
    cin>>midInitial;
    cout<<"Please enter your surname \n";
    cin>>lastName;

    getFullName = firstName+" "+midInitial+". "+lastName;
}

int addName()
{
    custName.insert (custName.end(), ',');
    custName.insert(custName.end(), getFullName);
}

int main ()
{
    getName();
    custName = getFullName;
    getName();
    addName();
    getName();
    addName();
    getName();
    addName();
    cout<<custName
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [`.append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::string::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) **doesn't have** a function signature like:

```
basic_string& insert( iterator pos, const basic_string& str );
```

update

```
custName.insert(custName.end(), getFullName);
```

to:

```
custName.insert(custName.end(), getFullName.begin(), getFullName.end());
```

or

```
custName.insert(distance(custName.end(), custName.begin()), getFullName);
```